# DDD integration: command handler questions?

Tags: c#, command, entity, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I use the DDD architecture and I'm having a hard time understanding some things.

This is the scheme of my project:
[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xGOk.png)

First of all, before asking my questions I will put an example and then I will ask the questions.

Suppose we want to manage the hours a worker works for a company, we have the following aggregates:

**TimeTracking** (entity root)

- HourTrackginID
- CompanyID
- WorkerID
- EntryTime
- ExitTime

**Worker** (entity)

- WorkerID
- CompanyID
- AllowTimeTracking
- ListOfWorkerHolidays

**Company** (entity)

- CompanyID
- AllowTimeTracking
- ListOfCompanyHolidays

**Holidays** (Value object)

- HolidaysID
- StartDate
- EndDate

And from our WPF application or WebService (using and app or whatever) we send the companyID and the workerID using a command.

And my questions are the following:

1. I receive a command with only the workerID and the companyID but I obviously need to retrieve the information of these entities and the TimeTrackerID (if the worker does not have and ExitTime). Where should this be done? In the command handler via repository? Or the command should already contain all the information?
2. Suppose we have the information of the first point in the command handler, now we should create a TimeTracking aggregate root with the information we have. Then depending on the data we will call a DoExit()/DoEntry() function of the TimeTracking entity.  Who should be the in charge to add/update the TimeTracking? Should the functions validate the business rules like not being in holidays, allow tracking, etc, and return a true or false, and then the Command Handler execute the add/update? Or should the functions create a domain event of execute entry/exit to delegate the add/update?
3. On the other hand, how should I update the UI with possible errors in the command handler? For example the company does not exist, this should be notified in some way, so it would be a correct solution to return an object in the command handler with success/error and type of error? 
   And the same when validating bussiness rules, should I also return an object to comunicate the error? 
   So if we did the following: when calling a DoEntry() the company does not allow tracking I return an object error to the command handler which will also return this error, would be correct ?
4. Finally, for every action done that manipulates and entity (editing the worker, deleting a time tracking...) we need a command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is upside down.  I’m assuming a WorkerID can only be associate with a single Company, and an HourTrackingID can only be associated with a single Worker.  Normally your Aggregate Root is the “one” part of a “one to many” relationship, meaning Worker is the AR and TimeTracking is an aggregate.

Your Command would be ClockInWorker and pass the WorkerID.  CompanyID is unnecessary because this command doesn’t care who the worker works for, just that they clocked in.  This command would call the method Worker.DoEntry, which would create a TimeTracking record with an entry time.  Then you have another command ClockOutWorker which works in the same way but calls Worker.DoExit.

Data validation (checking if the workerID is valid) happens both in the API and in the command.  Assuming WorkerID is a guid, the API validates that it received an actual guid.  The API does not validate that the guid corresponds to a real worker – that’s up to the command.  The API ensures the request is syntactically valid, the Command ensures business rules are followed.

You don’t show whether Holidays belong to a Company or not.  If so, then the Company should validate the Holiday via a Company.CanWorkerLogTime(workerID, logDate) method all.  This is should be called from the Command before calling Worker.DoEntry.  You can get the CompanyID from the Worker.  If Holidays do not belong to the Company, then you would make HolidayService with a method CanWorkerLogTime(logDate)